# Need to hook a method pre checkout in magento

Tags: magento, events, hook

I have made a magento module, It has multiple methods, of which 1 method is ProcessOrderAction(), I want to call this method every time before i do final checkout, My config file is below.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <kodework_ongoing>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </kodework_ongoing>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>kodework_ongoing</module>
                    <frontName>ongoing</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
  
    </frontend>
 
 

</config>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you want to hook in? On the cart page or before the first step in checkout or on order success?

Comment: just before the final step of checkout, i need to grab cart details when the order gets placed so before the final confirmation step need to make the call and send the order request :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the event `checkout_cart_save_after` to hook into via an observer. This event is fired after the after a cart save usually called after changes with cart items.

To use this you need to update your `config.xml` with a call to your `observer` class and your method.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <kodework_ongoing>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </kodework_ongoing>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>kodework_ongoing</module>
                    <frontName>ongoing</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
        <!-- Hook into events start -->
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <kodework_ongoing>
                        <class>kodework_ongoing/observer</class> <!-- The observer class where with the ProcessOrderAction method -->
                        <method>ProcessOrderAction</method>
                    </kodework_ongoing>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_save_after>
        </events>
        <!-- Hook into events end -->
    </frontend>
</config>
```

As you can see you need an `observer` class `app/code/local/Kodework/Ongoing/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Kodework_Ongoing_Model_Observer
{
    public function ProcessOrderAction($observer)
    {
        $cart = $observer->getData('cart');
        $quote = $cart->getData('quote');
        $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

       // More logic...
    }
}
```